# Extension and Updates option under Tools in VS 2019 missing

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2019

I have visual studio 2019 and Tools > Extensions and Updates doesn't show up. I did some searching but the answers did not work in my case. I already tried looking in Tools > Customize > Commands > Menu Bar: Tools and looked under Add Command and clicked Reset All, but the option still doesn't show up. I have tried this on VS 2019 and 2022. Did this option get renamed? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent VS 2019 and VS 2022, it is now Extensions > Manage Extensions.